# If two friends each throw three coins, what is the probability that both friends get the same number of heads?

Tags: probability

I tried the following;

I think that order isn't important, but the number of head does. So I consider the cases in which there are

- 1 head
- 2 head
- 3 head
- 0 head

for each friend.
So if we think in the problem as ordered samples with repetition (of size 2) then as we have 4 cases for each friend, we can say that the total of possible cases is $(4)(4)=16$.

Now, the favorable cases are when each number of heads of the first friend coincides with the same number of heads of the second friend, but there are only four cases when that happens, i.e., when we get ordered samples of the style 1,1 or 2,2 or 3,3 or 0,0.

BUT the book´s answer is 5/16 and I have no idea where this came from.

Can somebody bring me a little help, please?

Comment: The cases you divided into are not equally likely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let both do their tossing and then let $B$ turn over each of her coins. Then the event you are looking for is that exactly three out of six coins show heads. Since $B$'s "trick" doesn't destroy any randomness or independency, the answer is
$$ \frac{6\choose 3}{2^6}=\frac{5}{16}.$$

Comment: Very clever approach!

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ denote the number of heads the first person got and $B$ the number of heads the second person got. Then
$$
P(A=0)=P(A=3)=1/8\\
P(A=1)=P(A=2)=3/8
$$
from this it follows that
$$
P(A,B=0)=P(A,B=3)=1/64\\
P(A,B=1)=P(A,B=2)=9/64
$$
When you add up these four, you get $\frac{20}{64}=\frac{5}{16}$.