# Probability of equal amount of heads

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume two gamblers throw coins randomly, and we are interested in probability that both end up with the same amount of heads.

[The answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182714/if-two-friends-each-throw-three-coins-what-is-the-probability-that-both-friends) suggests that it is enough to count the events where "exactly 3 out of six coins show heads". **Why is this the correct intepretation?**

I know that the answer is correct, since

$$ \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\j\end{array}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\left(\begin{array}{c}2n\\n\end{array}\right)$$

holds by straightforwardly summing all events with different possible numbers of heads.

However, why do we *understand* it as the same as "exactly 3 out of 6 heads", if there are events where all heads or none heads suffice?

Comment: Why not ask the user who posted that solution?

Comment: Note:  I think you missed the part where one person turns all of their's over.    That stage is critical.

Comment: @lulu I think that answer is too old to expect a reply. Either way, yes, I didn't understand why the part you mention is critical for the interpretation.

Comment: That user is still active on the site.   But, any way, if they both had $i$ Heads, then after turning them over one player has $3-i$ Heads, and $i+3-i=3$.

Comment: with 9000+ answers I would expect his inbox being flooded constantly. :) Ping @hagen-von-eitzen for a comment? Anyway, this seems to be getting off the topic

Comment: @lulu Thanks. Say they both have rolled 0 heads and 3 tails, $i = 0$. What do you mean by "turning them over" to get $ 3 - 0$ Heads and $0 + 3 - 0 = 3$, when the full sample is 6 tails here? Maybe I'm behind a language barrier for the term "turning over"?

Comment: It's a very clever trick.  Here:  "turning over" just means reversing the coins.  So if the chosen player started with $HTT$ they end with $THH$.

Comment: @lulu Oh, not at all how I understood it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lets even say they threw n coins each other. For any i < n the odds for a guy to get i heads is equal to the odds of getting n-i heads. So saying "whats the odds for both getting i heads" is the same as "whats the odds for one getting i heads and the second getting n-i heads?" if you sum up all the i's that smaller than n, you get the question "whats the odds to get n time heads for the both of them".